# How to get VSCode to open in current workspace?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on linux. I have multiple linux workspaces.

When I open a new file in VSCode in a new workspace, it opens a new tab in VSCode in the original workspace rather than a new instance of VSCode in the current workspace. That's really annoying behaviour and I'd like to change it so that when I'm in a workspace, any new attempt to open something in VSCode will appear in the current workspace. Is that possible?

For clarity:

I have a file open in WorkSpace 1 in VSCode.

I switch to WorkSpace 2 and want to open a different existing file.

This opens back in WorkSpace 1 in a new tab of VSCode but I want it to open in a new instance of VSCode in WorkSpace 2.

Basically I want the different WorkSpace isolated from each other as they are for different bits of work.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I understand correctly... You want to `create` a new file in the current workspace or are you `opening a file` while being in the current workspace?

Comment: WorkSpace 1 - I have an existing file open in VSCode, I switch to WorkSpace 2 and want to open a different existing file. It opens in a new tab in WorkSpace 1. I want it to open in WorkSpace 2.

Comment: You want a **NEW** VSC Window that shows Workspace2?

Comment: Yep, I want a new VSC window in workspace2 that only shows the files that I've opened while in workspace 2.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Command Line Option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) `-n` or `--new-window`

Comment: I *think* that does what I want, thanks! I'll test it to make sure.